# Laravel search database table for partial match from query

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, laravel

I would like to write a search query that uses a supplied phrase to search a table and return the first value that matches any part of the phrase. Like using `str_contains()` or `starts_with()` to use to match.

The query i have needs to match the entire value otherwise it will always return null.

This is to check if an address exists in a database table.

```
$addressvalidation = CheckAddress::where('address', '=', $fulladdress)->value('address');
```

`$fulladdress` is the partial address like `1 Infinite Loop Cupertino` that i want to use to search in the database for a match.

`CheckAddress` is the query model for the table.

`address` is the column name in the table.

The problem is that i can't use `str_contains()` or `starts_with()` to query the database with the partial phrase. The query gets a hit if i match the entire value like `1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 95014`

Comment: try [like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator

Comment: @huuuk How would i write or format the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$addressvalidation = CheckAddress::where('address', 'like', "%{$fulladdress}%")->value('address');
```

Also, checkout the documentation for where statements: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses